# ViewPager and PagerAdapter, get Drawable

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Hello I have a **ViewPager** binded to a custom **PagerAdapter**.

The layout only has an **ImageView** and I would like to get the drawable of this imageView, on a button press. I added this method to the **PagerAdapter**:

```
public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return imageView.getDrawable();
}
```

In the **Activity**, on the button click, I execute this:

```
((MyAdapter)(mViewPager.getAdapter())).getDrawable();
```

The problem is that I obtain the forward image and not the current one, as I would like.

How to solve this?

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 private final ArrayList<Images> mImages;
 private Context context;
 private ImageView imageView;


public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Images> images) {
    this.context = context;
    mImages = images;
}

public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return imageView.getDrawable();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

    final String image = mImages.get(position).getFilename();

    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    final int width = ImageGalleryUtils.getScreenWidth(context);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(image)) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(image)
                into(imageView); 
    } else {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
 return view;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mImages.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing your adapter? you pass an arraylist of imageviews? You need this in order to get the correct imageview, based on the position:

In your activity you should call:

```
((MyAdapter)(mViewPager.getAdapter())).getDrawable(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

So first when you initialize your adapter pass the dataset like this:

```
private ArrayList<ImageView> mImageViews = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Images> mImages;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Images> images) { 
    this.context = context;
    mImages = images; 
}
```

Then on each item initialization
When you asign the imageview then copy the reference to the arraylist in that position.

```
imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
final String image = mImages.get(position).getFilename();
Context context = imageView.getContext();
final int width = ImageGalleryUtils.getScreenWidth(context);
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(image)){
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
    .load(image)
    .into(imageView);
} else {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
}
mImageViews.add(position, imageView);
```

So then you can access it in your method:

```
public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {
    return mImageViews.get(position).getDrawable();
}
```

Comment: I'm passing an ArrayList of Object, in which there are not the ImageView or the Drawable, but the URL of the Images.

Comment: Can you post more code? There si too much guessing from my part

Comment: I posted my adapter @silva96

Comment: By storing all the ImageViews in an ArrayList, am not I wasting RAM?

Comment: Its the only way, because if you have just one variable, it gets overwritten by the next initialization over and over.

Comment: Anyway, I tried as you suggested, but I have the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.add(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: I'm sorry forgot to initialize the arraylist, please see updated answer